# python perfomance, loop speed improvement

Tags: python, hadoop, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

The following function should do kernel regressions for prices of stocks against time for every 38 day period.

```
def kernelregressions(assetprices, windowperiod): #regresses prices on time
timeindex = np.linspace(1, assetprices.shape[0], assetprices.shape[0]) #time to start from 1 upto the length of the dataset
smoothprices = pd.DataFrame(index=timeindex, columns=assetprices.columns, dtype="float") # empty frame to store the smoothed prices
for symbol in assetprices.columns:
    for i in range(0,assetprices.shape[0]-windowperiod-1, windowperiod+1): #regressions are done for each 38 day period
        smoothprice = KernelReg(assetprices[symbol].iloc[i:i+windowperiod], 
                                timeindex[i:i+windowperiod], var_type="c", bw="cv_ls").fit()[0]
        smoothprices[symbol].iloc[i:i+windowperiod]= smoothprice
return smoothprices #returns smooth prices
```

The "assetprices" input is a pandas dataframe containing columns of stock prices, the window period is 38 in my case.

The above function takes **forever** to run when the dataframe has 100 stocks with price series of 500 days.

Is there any python module, package etc.. (or better way to do the loop)that I could make use of to speed up this function?
Is `Multiprocessing` or  `multithreading` applicable here?

Comment: You can use `multithreading` instead of`for symbol in assetprices.columns:` loop, as they don't have any shared variable, but if I understand correctly this code runs only once in 38 days so how long is **forever** that it is not enough ?

Comment: @It doesn't run once every 38 days. The kernel regression is done not once for the price series but for every 38 observations of the price i.e, from time 1 to t=38, then t=39 to 77, then t=78 to t=116 ...all the way to t=500.

Comment: My bad. But you can still use multithreading for the loop, and if using the `hadoop` as tag suggest, you can do it easily.

Comment: right.. thanks. But could you please write the code of how multithreading is included. I am not sure how it works...I am still a beginner in python

Comment: You should ask it in a different post. Only one question per post is allowed. Also others who know python better than me help you .  but for simple multithreading why not https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm